# Server Error Error: Convert JSBI instances to native numbers using `toNumber`

Tags: javascript, biginteger

When try to use JSBI.BigInt(wei) function of JSBI causing Issue.

It throughs Server Error:
Error: Convert JSBI instances to native numbers using `toNumber`.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet demonstrating what you're trying to do? What is `wei`? What does a `Server Error` have to do with it?

Comment: Basically, this is **Web3** stuff. **JSBI** (npm package) converts wei (which is the smallest unit of any crypto coin) to a number. A newer version of JSBI causing an issue that is the way I recommend version **3.2.5**.

Comment: I meant "what type of object is the variable `wei` in your code?". `JSBI.BigInt(x)` doesn't convert `x` to a `Number`. Maybe you meant `JSBI.toNumber(x)`. But sure, pin yourself to old versions and live with their bugs and limitations!

Answer (score 5):

This Problem is with newer versions of npm package JSBI.
Use Specifically version: "3.2.5"

```
npm uninstall jsbi
npm install jsbi@3.2.5
```